# How to merge video file with audio file and maintain creation time?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I was finicking around with youtube-dl and ended up downloading a video that youtube-dl wasn't able to merge the generated audio and video. After some investigation, I found that there was an issue in my ffmpeg config.

*Normally*, if you actually run youtube-dl a second time after fixing ffmpeg, it will automatically merge the files for you. But as fate would have it, the *online* video has since been deleted so youtube-dl freaks out.

Fortunately ffmpeg *itself* can also merge audio and video files, but loses a very nice feature youtube-dl's implementation has, keeping the creation time of the files (i.e. creation rather than download or publication time).

Is there any way to merge an audio and video file **and** keep the creation/last modified date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my own solution on a Mac OS (should work on any UNIX), partially adapted from https://superuser.com/a/277667/776444:

I'm sure there's a way to do this using only FFMPEG but I ended up using *touch*:

```
ffmpeg -i originalVideo.mp4 -i originalAudio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac combined.mp4

touch -r originalVideo.mp4 combined.mp4
```

Using these, I was able to change the file creation time for *combined.mp4* to 28 April 2020, to match *originalVideo.mp4*.

Comment: I was assuming you meant the optional `creation_time` metadata in the MP4 file.

Comment: I think my ffmpeg at least is configured to do that automatically when copying.